# Join compound table on itself in HQL

Tags: sql, hql

Is it possible to write this SQL statement in HQL?
If not, what are possible approaches in this case?

```
WITH t AS 
(SELECT DISTINCT * FROM reserv res 
INNER JOIN reservser rsr ON res.idreserv = rsr.idreserv
WHERE res.idorder = '12345')
SELECT * FROM t t1
LEFT JOIN t t2 ON t1.idreserv = t2.idreserv 
AND t1.arrival = t2.departure
```

Comment: That `sql` won't run in any databases I know of (`join` has to come before `where`).  Sample data and expected results would be helpful.

Comment: Why would you use a window function for such a simple query? You don't need it at all

Comment: @sgeddes, thank you, you're right, I've edited the code.

Comment: What error are you receiving?  I'm wondering if your common table expression results have duplicated columns since they both have `idreserv` columns?  Try changing your `select` list to just the columns you need.

Comment: @juergen d, there's a dozen of tables in subquery. Here's just a main idea for understanding.

Comment: @sgeddes,  There is no mistake, because no hql query mentioned here. This is working sql query, that i need to transform to hql, not to rewrite many strings of code during improvement.

Comment: I understand this is just a sample, but without the error you are receiving, it's going to be difficult to help.  `hql` supports `common table expressions` so that's not your problem.  Your query as is will return an error in every database I know because of duplicate columns (`select *` in the cte).  A CTE has to have unique columns defined.  Check this fiddle out as a simple example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5d7a1/1

Comment: @sgeddes, I've changed the topic name for better understanding. The mentioned SQL statement works (PostgreSQL) (no errors appearing), all I need is just to convert it to HQL.